# MySQL #1064 error for location finder

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the 10 entries that are closest to the user with the following search:

```
  $data_query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *
  111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
             * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
             + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) AS distance_in_km
 FROM merchants
 JOIN (
 SELECT  33.889676  AS latpoint,  151.193024 AS longpoint
) AS p ON 1=1
ORDER BY distance_in_km
LIMIT 15");
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(la' at line 2
```

I tried changing `SELECT *` to `SELECT latitude, longitude` (with `` but Stack Overflow keeps messing up syntax) but it's not doing much.

I'm new to `PHP` and `MySQL` so I'm feeling pretty out of depth as to what could be going wrong here.

Cheers :)

Comment: `SELECT * 111.045 *` Remove `*` after select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want also select *everything*, then add comma after first `*`: `SELECT *, 111.045 ...`

If not, then remove first `*`

Comment: woah this is depressing but thanks heaps guys! :)